in dual boot csm support is changed in bios
when i sue win 10 and then reboot to ubuntu, I can't use it because something changes csm support from disabled to enabled
using  boot repair I can't remove the problem

That setting is not one that normally can be changed from an operating system. Do you have a UEFI&BIOS mode? If so change to UEFI or UEFI only. Did you install both Ubuntu & Windows in UEFI mode? Some auto switch to match mode system is installed in.
